# handling Ajax Call in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

Yeah, I know it's a stupid question but I am struggling with this from past 3 hrs. I want to return a `ModelAndView` from my controller if `bindingResult.hasErrors()` resolves to true otherwise I want my method to return a response for an ajax call. I know that I need to annotate my method with `@ResponseBody` if I want my controller to generate the response but I don't understand **how to make my method either return a ModelAndView Object(when validation fails) or a String annotated with @ResponseBody(in the else part when everything goes fine)**. Can someone please guide me on this?

Here is my controller method.

```
@PostMapping("/problem/submit")
    public ModelAndView getProblemDetails(@Valid @ModelAttribute("problem") Problem problem,
                                        BindingResult bindingResult,ModelAndView modelAndView,Model model){
        modelAndView.setViewName("home");
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return modelAndView;
        }
        else{
            //return response for ajax call where my method return type should be String and it should be annotated with @ResponseBody
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alien suggested,Here you go:-

```
@PostMapping("/problem/submit")
public void getProblemDetails(@Valid @ModelAttribute("problem") Problem problem,BindingResult bindingResult,HttpServletResponse response){
    try {
        JSONObject resultJson = new JSONObject();
        resultJson.put("beanValidationFailed", false);
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            resultJson.put("beanValidationFailed", true);
            //private function to get bindingResult erros as key/value Pair
            resultJson = getFieldErrors(bindingResult,resultJson); 
        }else{
            //here retrunJson object is case of no errors
        }
        //This will bind this json directly to your AJAX response
        //You can use this json object to show error( in case of bindingResult erros as well send other data if there are no error) 
        response.getWriter().write(resultJson.toString());
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private JSONObject getFieldErrors(BindingResult bindingResult, JSONObject resultJson){
    try {
       List<FieldError> fieldErrors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
       for ( FieldError error: fieldErrors) {
          resultJson.put(error.getField(),error.getDefaultMessage());
       } 
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultJson;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple words you **CAN NOT** do that.

You can go with `javascript/jquery` validations. If everything validated successfully then you submit the form otherwise not.

Or else write a logic into your view page if there is no binding errors returned from the contoller.

http://www.raistudies.com/spring/spring-mvc/ajax-spring-mvc-3-annonations-jquery/